# Reference Request: Abelianization of free product is the direct sum of abelianizations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, algebraic-topology

[Abelianization of free product is the direct sum of abelianizations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736138/abelianization-of-free-product-is-the-direct-sum-of-abelianizations)

I am interested in the result above, and would like to study a textbook that delves into it deeper.

However the standard algebraic topology textbooks (e.g. Hatcher/Munkres) and standard algebra books like Hungerford do not contain this result.

Is there any suitable book that I can consult?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need a reference here? This is pretty straightforward to prove directly, since both are coproducts in their respective categories, and abelianization is a functor...

Comment: @SteveD : In general, functors do not commute with coproducts though ...

Comment: @Nicolas: this is a left adjoint functor though, so it does. I just didn't want to spell the whole thing out :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $\{G_i:i\in I\}$ be a collection of groups, $F$ be the free product of the $G_i$ and $A$ the direct sum of the abelianizations of the $G_i$. Free products, direct sums, and abelianizations all have universal properties. The universal property for the direct sum $A$ is that, for any abelian group $B$, we have

$$\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)=\prod_{i\in I}\mathrm{Hom}(G_i/[G_i,G_i],B)\text{.} $$

On the other hand, applying the universal property of abelianization, the free product, and finally abelianization again, gives

$$\mathrm{Hom}(F/[F,F],B)=\mathrm{Hom}(F,B)=\prod_{i\in I}\mathrm{Hom}(G_i,B)=\prod_{i\in I}\mathrm{Hom}(G_i/[G_i,G_i],B)$$.

These equalities (really canonical isomorphisms) constitute an isomorphism of functors $\mathrm{Hom}(A,-)\simeq\mathrm{Hom}(F/[F,F],-)$ from the category of abelian groups to the category of sets. Yoneda's lemma tells us that such an isomorphism is induced by a unique isomorphism $A\simeq F/[F,F]$.

Comment: Can the index set be infinite? (countable/uncountable) Is there any restriction?

Comment: Dear@yoyostein, Yes.

Comment: In $\text{Hom}(F,B) = \Pi_{i \in I} \text{Hom}(G_i,B)$, how should I understand the product symbol $\Pi$? When I look up the universal property of the free product, it is usually stated in this manner (without the product): https://www2.unb.ca/~ntouikan/MATH6022/IntroCGGT/html_output/universal.html, so I’m a bit confused.

Comment: In fact, a related question comes from reading my lecture note when it discusses the universal property of the coproduct:”Intuitively, this means that a map from the coproduct $X_1 \coprod X_2$ is equivalent to a pair of maps from $X_1$ and $X_2$”. I think the idea here is probably the same as the one you wrote? I’m uncertain as what “equivalent” really means.

Comment: Also, the maps that the universal properties claim to exist uniquely are often just homomorphisms. How do we get isomorphisms from them?

Answer (score 0):

This is Exercise 69.1 of Munkres' *Topology*.

The previous solution uses results not available in Munkres' textbook. Here I am giving an alternative solution that is more suitable for students following Munkres.

Our goal is to apply the "converse" part of **Lemma 67.5**.

[image: Lemma 67.5]

Since $[G_\alpha, G_\alpha] \in [G, G]$ for $\alpha = 1,2$, we have induced homomorphisms $i_\alpha: G_\alpha/[G_\alpha,G_\alpha] \rightarrow G/[G,G]$ such that $i_\alpha \circ \pi_\alpha = \pi$, where $\pi_\alpha$ is the quotient map $G_\alpha \rightarrow G_\alpha/[G_\alpha,G_\alpha]$ and $\pi$ is the quotient map $G\rightarrow G/[G,G]$.

$$\require{AMScd}
\require{cancel}
\def\diaguparrow#1{\smash{\raise.6em\rlap{\ \ \scriptstyle #1}
   \lower.6em{\cancelto{}{\Space{2em}{1.7em}{0px}}}}}
\begin{CD}
&& G_\alpha/[G_\alpha,G_\alpha] \\
& \diaguparrow{\pi_\alpha} @VV i_\alpha V \\
G_\alpha @>> \pi> G/[G,G]
\end{CD}$$

In particular, we want to show that given any abelian group $H$ and any family of homomorphism $h_\alpha: G_\alpha/[G_\alpha,G_\alpha] \rightarrow H$, there exists a homomorphism $h: G/[G,G] \rightarrow H$ such that $h \circ i_\alpha = h_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$.

$$\require{AMScd}
\require{cancel}
\def\diaguparrow#1{\smash{\raise.6em\rlap{\ \ \scriptstyle #1}
   \lower.6em{\cancelto{}{\Space{2em}{1.7em}{0px}}}}}
\begin{CD}
&& G/[G,G] \\
& \diaguparrow{i_\alpha} @VV h V \\
G_\alpha/[G_\alpha,G_\alpha] @>> h_\alpha> H
\end{CD}$$

Note that $h_\alpha \circ \pi_\alpha$ defines a homomorphism $G_\alpha \rightarrow H$. Applying **Lemma 68.1**, we have $h': G \rightarrow H$ whose restriction to $G_\alpha$ equals $h_\alpha \circ \pi_\alpha$, for each $\alpha$.

$$\require{AMScd}
\require{cancel}
\def\diaguparrow#1{\smash{\raise.6em\rlap{\ \ \scriptstyle #1}
   \lower.6em{\cancelto{}{\Space{2em}{1.7em}{0px}}}}}
\begin{CD}
&& G \\
& \diaguparrow{j_\alpha} @VV h' V \\
G_\alpha @>> h_\alpha \circ \pi_\alpha> H
\end{CD}$$

Now we apply Lemma 69.3 and $h': G \rightarrow H$ induces a homomorphism $h: G/[G,G] \rightarrow H$ such that $h \circ \pi = h'$.

$$\require{AMScd}
\require{cancel}
\def\diaguparrow#1{\smash{\raise.6em\rlap{\ \ \scriptstyle #1}
   \lower.6em{\cancelto{}{\Space{2em}{1.7em}{0px}}}}}
\begin{CD}
&& G/[G,G] \\
& \diaguparrow{\pi} @VV h V \\
G @>> h'> H
\end{CD}$$

We claim that $h \circ i_\alpha = h_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$, because for any $x \in G_\alpha$, we have $$h_\alpha \circ \pi_\alpha(x) = h'(x) = h \circ \pi(x) = h \circ i_\alpha \circ \pi_\alpha(x).$$

Q.E.D.